# Using AWS Toolkit in Visual Studio 2019 for LocalStack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-2019, localstack, aws-toolkit

Can the AWS Toolkit in Visual Studio 2019 be used to access LocalStack running on my development machine?

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to do this for a long time now. But unfortunately, I have gone through a significant number of configuration permutations without luck.

I believe that as long as custom endpoints are not allowed on AWS Toolkit, the answer will be "no."

Keep an eye on https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-vscode/issues/2007